# Is $\mathrm {rank}\ (AA^*A)= \mathrm {rank}\ (A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, transpose

Let $A \in \Bbb C^{m \times n}$ and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Then can we always have  $\mathrm {rank}\ (AA^*A)= \mathrm {rank}\ (A)$?

Please give me a counter-example if it doesn't hold at all.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, but I would start off by considering the fact that rank(A) = rank(A*) and also think about the (various) definition(s) of rank (I think the most useful in this case is the dimension of the image).  Also it may help to think of $A$ as a map from $C^n$ to $C^m$.

I'm inclined to believe the two are equal, but can't quite close the proof myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its true. I have used the superscript **H** to denote conjugate transpose.

We will use the result $rank(A^HA)= rank (AA^H)=rank(A)$

To see this, if $A^HAx =O$, then $x^HA^HAx =O \implies |Ax|^2 =O \implies Ax =O$

Thus, $nullity(A^HA) \subset nullity(A)$. The reverse inclusion is trivial.

So, $nullity(A^HA) = nullity(A)\implies n- |nullity(A^HA)| = n- |nullity(A)| 
\implies rank(A^HA)= rank(A) $

Now, let  $AA^HAx =O$

Write  $Ax =y$ , then $AA^Hy =O \implies A^Hy =O \implies A^HAx =O $

Thus,  $Ax =O \implies  nullity (AA^HA) = nullity (A)$

From here you get, $rank(AA^HA) = rank (A)$

Comment: How do you get $AA^Hy=O \implies A^Hy=O$?

Comment: I have taken $x$ an element of $nullity(AA^HA)$. Then write $Ax=y$, so $AA^Hy=O$

Comment: This is to prove that $nullity(AA^HA) \subset nullity(A)$. The reverse inclusion is trivially true, so equality follows.

Comment: I have used that result, which I mentioned in my 2nd line. I have also provided the proof in the 3rd line. Just write $A^H = B$, then $B^HBy =O$. The proof after that will be virtually same as what I have provided. So, $By =O \implies A^Hy =O$

Comment: $\mathrm {nullity} (AA^HA)$ is a number, not a set as it is the dimension of the null space of $AA^HA$.

Comment: By $nullity(AA^HA)$, I meant $ker(AA^HA)$ . You may be right about that.

Comment: Very nice proof. Good catch @Lord KK. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

If $v\in N(A)$ (the null space of $A$), then $v\in N(AA^*A)$. Suppose $v\in N(AA^*A)$; then also $A^*AA^*Av=0$ and therefore $v^*A^*AA^*Av=0$, which means
$$
(A^*Av)^*(A^*Av)=0
$$
so $A^*Av=0$. Then also $v^*A^*Av=0$, which means
$$
(Av)^*(Av)=0
$$
so $Av=0$.

Hence $N(A)=N(AA^*A)$. Apply the rank-nullity theorem.